# Redis и Openserver

Tags: openserver, redis

Доброго времени суток, ситуация такая. Ноутбук 32 бит. Установлен OpenServer. Redis в опенсервере доступен только с 64 битной системой. 
Я установил `redis-2.4.6-setup-32-bit` ([ссылка](https://code.google.com/archive/p/buddypress-media/downloads)) в `OpenServer/modules/redis`. После этого в `php.ini` прописал `extension=php_redis-2.1.3-5.3-ts.dll` ([фото](http://prntscr.com/ijmsfv)). И еще в `OpenServer/modules/php/PHP-5.6/ext` добавил `php_redis-2.1.3-5.3-ts.dll` ([фото](http://prntscr.com/ijmtcq)). Но при настройках в Openserver в модуле не могу подключить Redis ([фото](http://prntscr.com/ijmus4)). Если поработать с ним в папке на сервере, то всек ок([фото консоли](http://prntscr.com/ijn9gb)). Я уже не знаю что делать. Буду рад принять советы или помощь в решении.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создаем папку **OpenServer\modules\redis\Redis-2.4**, внутрь заливаем ехе-шники скачанного Вами Redis.
2. Создаем конфиг **OpenServer\userdata\config\Redis-2.4.conf**, содержимое можно скопировать из уже существующего **Redis-2.8.conf**.
3. Копируем **php_redis-2.1.3-5.3-ts.dll** в **OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\ext\**.
4. В конфиге PHP(**OpenServer\userdata\config\PHP-5.6_php.ini**) комментируем или удаляем строчку **extension=php_redis.dll** и добавляем **extension=php_redis-2.1.3-5.3-ts.dll**.
5. Запускаем **OpenServer** и включаем установленный **Redis-2.4** модуль.

Comment: Сделал все как написали, но опять та же ошибка http://prntscr.com/ipmld5

Comment: Скачал redis-2.4.6-setup-32-bit.exe и установил его в OpenServer\modules\redis\Redis-2.4 (http://prntscr.com/ipmn66) и дальше все по Вашему гайду. Но в настройках модулей опенсервера при выборе Redis-2.4 выводит (http://prntscr.com/ipmnhp)